# Rgbdslam in ros hydro

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, ros-hydro, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use the rgbdslam package in ROS Hydro (on Ubuntu 12.04), but I'm experiencing some difficulties. First of all I had to install the arm_navigation stack and the octomap_server (I used the hydro-devel catkin version for this one), and I managed to do it. Now the problem is in the rgbdslam package. After following those instructions for groovy:

http://answers.ros.org/question/74899/rosmake-rgbdslam_freiburg-error-in-groovy/ (can't post the right link due to lack of karma),

I'm now trying to build it with rosbuild, but for now it gives me the error:

octomap_ros/OctomapROS.h: No such file or directory

I've seen that this file has been removed in Hydro. Moreover I suppose I will have to change something for the usage of point cloud library, since in hydro has changed very much. Can someone help me to use the rgbdslam in hydro?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91111/rgbdslam-in-ros-hydro/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 808 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to resolve the problem. The easier way is to add the header file OctomapROS.h in the folder /opt/ros/hydro/include/octomap_ros/. In such a way though it is a deprecated file the rgbdslam can find what it needs. For the pcl library I used the pcl_conversions to convert all headers of point cloud (where needed) from pcl type to ros msg and vice versa, as explained in the hydro migration page.
Now the rgbdslam works fine!

EDIT: can someone mark this answer as correct? (I can't due to lack of karma)

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-10-22**:
Just keep in mind that the header OctomapROS.h was already deprecated for groovy and is gone for good since hydro. The cleanest solution would be to fix RGBD-Slam such that it's no longer including it.

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-12-02**:
@Tirjen Could you maybe upload your new source files? Cause it is a never ending task to change the codes line by   line. You can send me per mail or share it here with everyone, maybe ;)
Mail: patrick dot wiesen at gmail dot com

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-12-15**:
Unfortunately I cannot do that because I'm not using anymore the pc on which I installed the rgbdslam. If I will have access again to that pc I will do it! Anyway I assure you that doing it by yourself is a 10-minutes work! ;)

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-03-09**:
As Jiangtao says, the problem could be related to the topics you are listening to. Did you check it?

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-03-26**:
Having the same problem as @lguodongustc. any idea what ros topics should be listened? It gives me this warning:

WARNING: [/home/tsc/catkin_ws_hydro/src/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/launch/kinect+rgbdslam.launch] unknown  attribute 'no-launch-prefix'

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
@TSC @lguodongustc What kind of workspace do you install the RGBDSLAM package, catkin or rosbuild? Also, do you install arm_navigation stack and the octomap_server? It says that they are deprecated in Groovy and Hydro.